# German - English dictionary

Tags: data-request, dictionary

I'm looking for a simple German - English dictionary (txt, CSV or some other easy-to-parse format)

I need only German nouns with their gender, plural form (optional) and translation to English. I've tried to Google some, but I've been unsuccessful :( Do you guys have any tips, where should I look? :)

*It's for a non-profit open-source educational game, so a license shouldn't be issued.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If GPL licenced is acceptable to you, then you can use the German <-> English dictionary included in the Ding package:

http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~fri/ding/

Answer (score 5):

The [dict.cc dictionary](http://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e) is available to download as a machine readable text file (tab-delimited, UTF-8), with free registration. There are some licensing terms, mostly related to not sharing the data set (but you can share what you create, of course).

In addition to German <-> English, many other language pairs are available under the same terms

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure for 100% that you can do all of what you want with [wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

I have used it a few months before with Python and it has many many options. Have you tried it? Maybe there are more functionalities that can help you.

Comment: Isn't the Princeton wordnet a monolingual English resource? But there is the Open Multilingual Wordnet at http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/ – unfortunately it does not feature German yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack (some might consider it ugly):

- Download the english and the german wikipedia and/or wiktionary
- Make a list of articles that are translations of each other
- Use the page titles as words of your dictionary

I admit, this is not an easy-to-parse format, but a huge data source that is sometimes overlooked.

Comment: This is a prospect but how will he retrieve the information he asks from your process? He doesn't want just a translation dictionary, but a dictionary with nouns and genders and optional the plurar form.

Comment: True, in this case, wikipedia is not very useful, but wiktionary still is.

Answer (score 2):

This question is 8 years old but as i couldn't find an straight forward answer in 2022 I'm sharing it here.

Wiktionary is the best resource for both monolingual and bilingual dictionaries in terms of licensing and diversity. but parsing it is a bit tricky. fortunately  Karl Bartel has already done it and you can download already parsed and updated dictionaries [here](https://www.wikdict.com/page/download).

Answer (score 1):

there is many dictionaries database of all languages you need in https://apkpure.com
1 - choose an application of dictionary you need
2 - download the file APK on your disk
3 - rename the APK extension to zip ans extract the files
4 - look into the biggest file in list of files ( certainely it's the database)
5 - use SQLite explorer , and open this file .. you can export it to csv

Comment: This *is* a possible way, but very roundabout and probably against the terms of use of those apps.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, five answers an no one even mentioned the very obvious choice: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page). I recommend starting from the English language Wiktionary, extract the words tagged as German, filter by part-of-speech. All requested information (and many more) is available there.

Answer (score 1):

The parsed Wiktionary under https://kaikki.org/dictionary/German/ in JSON (lines) is also very easy to use and contains a lot of data.