# Speech audio files dataset with language labels

Tags: language, machine-learning, audio

I am working on building a language classifier in speech/audio samples. I have been trying to find a dataset which may have considerable number of speech samples in various languages. The audio files maybe of any standard format like wav, mp3 etc. containing human voice/conversation with least amount of background noise/music.

I am unable to find any such dataset. Can someone share link of any speech dataset that may be good for this research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/) website which has full sentences in text and audio as [downloads](http://tatoeba.org/eng/downloads).

> **Sentences with audio**
>
> Download
>
> http://downloads.tatoeba.org/exports/sentences_with_audio.tar.bz2
>
> Fields and structure
>
> ```
> Sentence id
> ```
>
> File description
>
> ```
> Contains the ids of the sentences, in all languages, for which audio is available.
> ```

Thanks to [Nicolas Raoul](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/754/nicolas-raoul) in [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3926/1511).

Answer (score 8):

I suggest looking at the SpokenLanguages2 dataset, which is very extensive, containing a bit more than one hour of speech for each of the 172 languages: https://community.topcoder.com/longcontest/?module=ViewProblemStatement&rd=16555&pm=13978

The audio is very high quality. Although they do not provide access to the testing set, you have to do your own split.

Comment: Be careful: I downloaded its [Training Dataset List](http://www.topcoder.com/contest/problem/SpokenLanguages2/trainingData.csv) and among its labels it does not have common languages such as Spanish or english

Answer (score 7):

UCLA Phonetics Lab Archive offers many audio files of spoken word in many languages, although you'll have to dig through and mix-match to your liking:
http://archive.phonetics.ucla.edu/
IPA Handbook downloads actually seems to be exactly what you are asking for, however its only for personal use; any other usage requires contacting them for permission...so not 100% open data:
https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/ipa-handbook-downloads

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can do something with https://rhinospike.com/language/ It's a bit like Tatoeba mentioned above

edit : Take also a look at librivox (public domain audiobooks). It comes with an API, then you could send a request like [https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks?fields={url_zip_file,language}&offset=XXX&limit=YYY](https://librivox.org/api/feed/audiobooks?fields=%7Burl_zip_file,language%7D&offset=XXX&limit=YYY) to extract files' id

Comment: Feel free to post an answer for each. Also, please specify about how many languages each one covers. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I've found something else. It is called the *wide language index*. See on [github](https://github.com/larsyencken/wide-language-index). It consists in a listing of radio podcasts. It's pretty impressive in the numbers of languages covered.

Note : It was made for the game [*The Great language game*](https://greatlanguagegame.com) which is fun ;).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check this website, it collects many audio-related datasets.

https://www.audiocontentanalysis.org/data-sets/