# Open Translations of Documents

Tags: translation

I just put together some [open translations](https://github.com/7-rabbit/8-text/tree/master/content/rabbit-hole) of an open document. It has the english version and several other languages.

I'm wondering if there is anything else like this that is open. Some free documents that have translations into multiple languages. I can imagine the Bible is, but I'm not sure the translations are free and open (if they are please correct me). I have seen constitutions in the source language perhaps translated into English, but other than that I can't think of any.

Wondering if one could put together a list of some of the documents which have at least a one or a few translations which are also free / open / public domain.

Comment: Interesting question that reminded me of this one: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3888/1511, and this comment all the way at the bottom: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/dataset-of-sentences-translated-into-many-languages/3894#comment4014_3894 , which has many hundred professional translations of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights

Comment: Nice! Thanks :) https://github.com/7-rabbit/8-text/tree/master/content/universal-declaration-of-rights