# I am looking for good german <-> czech dictionary in text format(or something else)

Tags: data-request, language, dictionary

I am looking for good german <-> czech dictionary in text format (or something I can easy read).

The Idea behind is I would like to program a program for myself for learning czech, but the sources I found online are not good.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the answer below is useful, can you please mark it as "accepted". If not, can you please edit your question to indicate what you are looking for. (Also, please see this answer http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1614/1511 )

Answer (score 2):

The dict.cc website has German (DE) to Czech (CS) translations, among many other languages to German or English.

**http://csde.dict.cc/**

They also offer a [bulk download](http://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e), with the following (abbreviated) terms:

> Utilizing the data for personal use is granted provided that the data is not given away to third parties or published in any way.

and they mention software released must be [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) and that you can't reshare the data.

Anyway, the terms are friendly for your personal use, so you can fill out the email form and request your download link. You can choose either CS-to-DE or DE-to-CS, which is just the sorting.

---

*([similar answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1614/1511))*

*((I used this data source to make [this chart](http://philshem.github.io/nouns.html)))*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [Czech-German Tabfile](https://github.com/Vuizur/dewiktionary-htmldump-parser/releases/tag/1.0.0) that I created by [parsing](https://github.com/Vuizur/dewiktionary-htmldump-parser) the German Wiktionary.

Another option (I haven't tested yet) could be https://github.com/kakaobrain/word2word. Or you could create your own dictionary with the help of translated sentence pairs from Tatoeba or CCMatrix (maybe I'll work on it too).