# translation dictionaries for european languages

Tags: data-request, language, dictionary, translation

I'm looking for open translation dictionaries of european languages. Most important would be english-french and english-spanish.

This question is a direct analogon to:

- [Translation dictionaries](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/translation-dictionaries). The title of this question very broad, but it has been most interested in english-japanese. And it has been resolved with a dataset on english-japanese
- [German - English dictionary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/german-english-dictionary?noredirect=1&lq=1). This question is specifically on english-german.

I've already found:

- [dict.cc allows you do download dictionaries](https://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e) of their language pairs. The data looks great, very clean and with lots of entries. But you may only use it if your software is GPL (maybe possible) and if you don't bundle the data, but link back to the dict.cc site, for users to download it (huge problem, software should be self-contained).
- extracting translations from wiktionary, [like in this project](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Matthias_Buchmeier/en-fr-a). But the data is not that clean and creating it for other language pairs would be a considerable overhead in scraping/processing.